# How to remove word between the slashes?

Tags: sed

I need regexp which would remove tinrab in all directories

```
grep -rl "tinrab" /home/miki/go/src/github.com/meower
/home/miki/go/src/github.com/meower/pusher-service/main.go
/home/miki/go/src/github.com/meower/Dockerfile
/home/miki/go/src/github.com/meower/event/nats.go
/home/miki/go/src/github.com/meower/event/event.go
/home/miki/go/src/github.com/meower/meow-service/handlers.go
/home/miki/go/src/github.com/meower/meow-service/main.go
/home/miki/go/src/github.com/meower/query-service/handlers.go
/home/miki/go/src/github.com/meower/query-service/main.go
/home/miki/go/src/github.com/meower/search/elastic.go
/home/miki/go/src/github.com/meower/search/repository.go
/home/miki/go/src/github.com/meower/Gopkg.lock
/home/miki/go/src/github.com/meower/Gopkg.toml
/home/miki/go/src/github.com/meower/db/repository.go
/home/miki/go/src/github.com/meower/db/postgres.go
/home/miki/go/src/github.com/meower/.git/logs/HEAD
/home/miki/go/src/github.com/meower/.git/logs/refs/heads/master
/home/miki/go/src/github.com/meower/.git/logs/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
/home/miki/go/src/github.com/meower/.git/config
```

For example in Dockerfile I have this line

```
WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/tinrab/meower
```

My goal is to have line without tinrab

```
WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/meower
```

This regexp

```
replaceAll("/tinrab*/ *", " ")
```

should somehow be implemented.
Any ideas?

If I try

```
grep -rl "tinrab" /home/miki/go/src/github.com/meower | xargs replaceAll("\/tinrab\/", "")
```

I got

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Comment: `replaceAll("\/tinrab\/", "")`?

Comment: What's the rationale behind removing that string? If you want to remove that string literally, then you don't need regex and can remove using string replace function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said you wanted a regexp `/tinrab*/ *`, but based on the examples you gave I guess `/tinrab` will do what you want..

```
grep -rl "tinrab" /home/miki/go/src/github.com/meower | \
  xargs -r sed -i 's!/tinrab!!g'
```

The general format of the sed expression I used is: `s!<from>!<to>!g` which works the same as the `replaceAll("<from>", "<to>")` pseudocode you considered.